# Defining a dynamic directive template based on link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build my own "ng-repeat" as practice in Angular 1.6.
So I was thinking:
I get the element at the end (link), do a "forEach" loop on the element based on the scope variable and so on...
The problem is that my template needs to be dynamic, I don't know what is the element that the "new ng-repeat" is on.
I have tried something like this, but it won't work:

```
myApp.directive("nirtz-repeat", function() {
  return {
    restrict : "A",
    link : function (s,e,a) {
      console.log(s);
      console.log(e);
      console.log(a);
      return "<customElement>Example</customElement>";
    },
    template : this.link
  };
});
```

Comment: Angular is open source, go watch the repository code source on github.

Comment: @ArDumez Interesting, I'll take a look.